# Rewrite the method using new namespace - Azure.Storage.Files.Shares

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-files, fileshare, storage-file-share

I want to re-write the method which is using "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File" to "Azure.Storage.Files.Shares". This method is copying file to fileshare using sasuri.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Data model for attachment content
    /// </summary>
    public class Attachment
    {
      /// <summary>
      /// File Name
      /// </summary>
      public string FileName { get; set; }

      /// <summary>
      /// FileContent
      /// </summary>
      public string Content { get; set; }
    
     /// <summary>
     /// File Type
     /// </summary>
     public string ContentType { get; set; }
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// CopyFileToShareAsync
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sasUri"></param>
    /// <param name="attachment"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task CopyFileToShareAsync(string sasUri, Attachment attachment)
    {
        var cloudFileDirectory = new CloudFileDirectory(new Uri(sasUri));

        var cloudFile = cloudFileDirectory.GetFileReference(attachment.FileName);

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Content);

        await cloudFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(new MemoryStream(bytes));
    }
```

Comment: So, docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azurestoragefilesshares-samples/). Do you have some specific problem?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.shares-readme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sasUri = "https://account-name.file.core.windows.net/share-name?sv=2020-04-08&se=2021-03-30T18%3A30%3A00Z&sr=s&sp=cw&sig=ZYXpOsCwP6uBOudbEu3TWwBAPc%2BOefu%2B%2F0lKl5ls3k8%3D";
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            FileName = "sample.text",
            Content = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some content")),
            ContentType = "text/plain"
        };
        CopyFileToShareAsync(sasUri, attachment).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Content uploaded");
    }

    static async Task CopyFileToShareAsync(string sasUri, Attachment attachment)
    {
        ShareDirectoryClient shareDirectoryClient = new ShareDirectoryClient(new Uri(sasUri));
        ShareFileClient shareFileClient = shareDirectoryClient.GetFileClient(attachment.FileName);
        byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Content);
        await shareFileClient.CreateAsync(fileContent.Length, new Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.Models.ShareFileHttpHeaders()
        {
            ContentType = attachment.ContentType
        });
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContent))
        {
            await shareFileClient.UploadAsync(ms);
        }
    }
}

public class Attachment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// File Name
    /// </summary>
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FileContent
    /// </summary>
    public string Content { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// File Type
    /// </summary>
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you append to an existing file on Azure File Share?